# How to reference JS in an html file

Tags: javascript, reference

I have been trying to reference my JS in my html file for a while now. I have tried many different methods that people have told me and none of them have worked. Here is what I have at the moment. `<script src="script.js"></script>` Yes, both files are in the same folder along with my style.css file. The reference I have for the style.css file works. I used `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />`
Can someone please help me fix my JS reference?

Comment: That's the correct way to do it. What's not working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: add your code, which is not working

Comment: Can you share some screenshot or code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If its doesn't work check console for any problem Or check directory of script src!

Answer (score 0):

someways javascript is disable on your web browser . check it and enable .

Comment: That was the first thing I checked. I have it on.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
<script src="/script.js"></script>
```

Some web servers might want that leading slash, while others don't need it.

Comment: Thank you I will try it!

Comment: This did not work. I must have something wrong.

Comment: Could you copy/paste your code in here so we can see it? Also, what web server are you using?

Comment: ```<script src="/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<div id="activity">
   <img src="http://code.quirkbot.com/assets/images/logo/white-outline.svg" width="30%" alt="">
  <h1 id="counter">You have hit the D Key <span class="hits">0</span> times.</h1>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/emery.aiden">Follow @emery.aiden on Instagram!<p>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/emeryaiden32/">Follow emeryaiden32 on Twitter!<p>
  <a href="#" onclick="resetHits()" class="tryagain">RESET!</a>
  </div>``` Here is my code.

Comment: What type of server are you using? How do you access that index.html (URL)?